# DOMXpath remove tag

Tags: php, parsing, domdocument, domxpath

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class ="lvlone">
    <div class = "lvltwo"> Hello
        <span>World</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I do this:`$res = $xpath->query(//div[@class='lvlone']/div[@class='lvltwo']);`

I get `Hello World` including the string in `<span>` tag but i down want it!
I only want the `Hello`.
What can i do ?
Thanks!

Comment: You're probably going to need to use `text()` at some point to extract only text nodes and not other children. I'd start looking there.

Comment: thanks man! I am new at DOMDocument and i didnt find this at PHP.net!

Comment: No problem, I remember learning XPath... oh wait no, I'm _still_ learning my way around XPath! Haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As TheZ points out, you can use the `text()` function from XPath:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query( '//div[@class="lvltwo"]/text()');
echo $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue; // Prints 'Hello'
```